# Add Inputs to a Form from a Child Component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to generate inputs based on pass in data. Each of the inputs are their own components to allow for more modifications/functionality later on.

Then have a form processor that contains a button that on click, works with what the form has.

Problem I'm having is I get the form when I click a button to process it, but all the values are empty and I can't see anything in the form that even makes it look like it recognized the inputs were there.

Root Form:

```
<form #inputForm="ngForm">
  <div *ngFor="let d of data">
    <app-input [name]="d.name" [label]="d.label"></app-input>
  </div>
</form>
<app-form-processor [inputForm]="inputForm"></app-form-processor>
```

Input Class:

```
<label>{{label}}</label>
<div>
  <input [(ngModel)]="name" [name]="name">
</div>
```

Form Processor:

```
<button (click)="processForm()">Process</button>
```

Form Processor (partial code):

```
@Input() inputForm: NgForm;

generateStatement() {
  console.log(this.inputForm);
}
```

Console log just has an ngForm that is empty of any values (and pretty much anything else outside of the defaults an ngForm has)

**Note that if I paste the contents of the input class straight into the ngForm (instead of using a child component) it works fine, but I would like to use a child component if possible.**

Comment: You can make your component to implement ControlAccessor and act as form controll

Comment: Are you talked about ControlValueAccessor?

Comment: yep thats the one

Comment: Looks promising, by the description it's exactly what I need. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going with Antoniossss 's suggestion I looked up ControlValueAccessor and found this tutorial that led me to get something working.

https://medium.com/@tarik.nzl/angular-2-custom-form-control-with-validation-json-input-2b4cf9bc2d73